# how to rise an alert over a data in dataframe in Apahe Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, alert

i have  a dataframe i just did "sum" on two columns ( columns of int type) .as("addition)
i want to raise an alert if a value of the "Addition" column is exceeded (greater than 3)

thank you

Comment: Could you provide more details of data and what type of alert you want . please explain with an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is an example of how you can do. You can filter (or do any other action) on `alert` column of the `sumDF` DataFrame.

```
val nums = Seq(
    (1, 2),
    (4, 4),
    (0, 3)
  ).toDF("col1", "col2")

  val sumDF = nums
    .withColumn("addition", nums("col1") + nums("col2"))
  sumDF.show()

//  +----+----+--------+
//  |col1|col2|addition|
//  +----+----+--------+
//  |   1|   2|       3|
//  |   4|   4|       8|
//  |   0|   3|       3|
//  +----+----+--------+
  sumDF
    .withColumn("alert", sumDF("addition") > 3)
    .show()
//  +----+----+--------+-----+
//  |col1|col2|addition|alert|
//  +----+----+--------+-----+
//  |   1|   2|       3|false|
//  |   4|   4|       8| true|
//  |   0|   3|       3|false|
//  +----+----+--------+-----+
```